# php performance questions on storing user object in sessions

Tags: php, performance

I have a user based web app that I am putting together.  The system creates a user object at login and then stores it in the session array.  On each page load the system validates the session data against a session key stored in the database and checks to see if any data related to the user has been changed (bool flag in the user table).  If data has been changed the user object is recreated, otherwise I use the one stored in sessions.  It looks something like:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
 $flags = get_session_flags($_SESSION['session_key']);
 if (!$flags['valid_session_key'])
 {
  logout();
  redirect_to_home();
 }
 if ($flags['user_data_changed'])
 {
  $user = recreate_user_object();
 }
 else
 {
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
 }
}
```

My concerns are about php/mysql server performance.  What possible issues might I run into storing the user object between page loads?  Should I just always pull the data fresh from the db?  It is a significant amount of information including several activity based objects stored inside the user object.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> The system creates a user object at
>   login and then stores it in the
>   session array.

What constitutes a User object? How much of the User object will you utilize? Do you constantly need all the data it offers?

> On each page load the system validates
>   the session data against a session key
>   stored in the database and checks to
>   see if any data related to the user
>   has been changed (bool flag in the
>   user table).

How often is the user data updated? If it's only updated on a few pages, then doing the check every page load seems a bit much. The previous question still holds though as what constitutes rebuilding a User object.

Comment: The user object holds both personal data and objects related to the user's activity on the site.  Some of the personal data and a portion of every activity object is used on each page as part of the page navigation.  The modification check is stored in the same table that holds the session keys and is done because admins are able to edit activity related data for individual users.  thanks